# Trying to Convert Label that is number to int

Tags: javascript, html, function, label, typeconverter

I've been trying to convert a label to an int to do an equation. I haven't been able to use ConvertToInt32() or ParseInt(). I've been getting back NaN each time. Please help! Here's my code:

```
    <div id="width"> <strong>Roll Width: </strong><label id="lblRollWidth"       type="number">25</label></div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</div>


 <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="">
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="calc()">Calculate</a>
        <input type="text" name="output" id="output" value="">

  <script>

 function calc(){

 var textValue1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
 var textValue2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
 var textValue3 = document.getElementById('lblRollWidth').value;




       document.getElementById('output').value = textValue1 * textValue2 * textValue3; 
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change :

```
var textValue3 = document.getElementById('lblRollWidth').value;
```

to

```
var textValue3 = +document.getElementById('lblRollWidth').innerText;
```

because it is a label, therefore to get its value you have to use .innerText.

Also, not mandatory, but recommendended, change:

```
 var textValue1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
 var textValue2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
```

to:

```
 var textValue1 = +document.getElementById('input1').value;
 var textValue2 = +document.getElementById('input2').value;
```

So that they will be casted as numbers.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m1brLkqx/

Also, as a side note, NaN is being thrown because of the label, the rest was working.

Comment: good! don't forget to accept the answer in order to "close" the question and to don't keep it unanswered (if you don't have any other question). Also, forgot to explain that, but using the unary operator (+) is the exact same as doing parseInt(), in such a case, it's just faster and easier to read, in my opinion.